# Xcode Cloud build from Flutter project unable to find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode-cloud

I have no problem building ios project the traditional way, but when trying to build with Xcode Cloud it seems that there is some trouble in finding specific paths. I'm importing the build from the repository, is there a possibility that pod files don't get installed, or does Flutter projects need some additional tweaking that I am missing.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should add post-clone script.

See https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/cd#xcode-cloud.

Answer (score 1):

The command that generates `Generated.xcconfig` for me is `flutter pub get`. Make sure that command runs and it succeeds. My problem was that it was silently failing (as part of `ci_post_clone.sh`) even though it did log the error "Expected to find project root in current working directory."

Comment: flutter clean and flutter pub get. worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem changing the installation of Pods adding this line to ci_post_clone.sh:

I changed:
cd ios && pod install

To:
$CI_WORKSPACE/repository_name/ios && pod install

You have to know that path needs to be exactly.